# Storing Action Rules

Tags: c#, postgresql, rule-engine, .net-core-3.1

I have an application that receives data from IoT devices, information such as temperature, water level and so on.

I need to implement a way to store a rule for a device, for example the user can specify "if Temperature is > 30, Send Message / Preform action". so Parameter A >/== Value then do X.

How would I store the rule in a DB so I can run a job on those rules every X Min? Running the Jobs is simple enough, I can do the technical side, but I am just stumped on the Storage logic.

If we can do it recursively / Nested statements, it would be great but I'm just looking for some simple guidance to start.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A full formatted example of the rules an device can have would be helpful. Also how are the devices dealt with in the database? In other words is/are there table(s) that hold information by device? An outline of the schema that does that would also be helpful.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, the Data is stored in a dataLogTable, that stores the DeviceSerialNumber, Param1(Temp),Param2(Level),Param3(Day/Night) as they come in from a Json Message sent by the device. There are  20 Parameters that are sent by the Device, Most of them are converted from Json to fields such Double(temp, Level, Humidity), With a few Bool(open/closed,day/night), Timestamp. A device is is Own Object, (DeviceID,SerialNumber, Name). One device can have many DataLog entry's as the Messages come in. The Device Rule will be run on the DataLog Table, I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Are the rules going to be run in the job by the application? If so I would create a ```rules``` table that has the ```rule_id```(PK) ,```device_id ```  and ```rule_fld``` (as varchar). Where a device could have many rules. Then on the interval grab the rules for the device_id and  process them.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this with a rule table, a conditions table and an
actions table, with the latter 2 having an FK to the 1st. The conditions
table would also have a column indicating which field to test, a
column indicating the operator, and a column indicating the value to
compare it with ('>' and 30 in your example). Actions table just has a
column for indicating the action and maybe an additional one for extra
details (perhaps "send email" and "foo@example.com", respectively);
this would be a decent candidate for a jsonb column since the actions
likely have widely varying pieces of additional data needed to do
their job.

Your job would just join the conditions table with the recent data
points, probably using a WHERE timestamp > the last time the job ran.

```
SELECT actions.* FROM
data_table t
JOIN rules on rules.device_id=t.device_id
JOIN conditions on conditions.rule_id=rules.id
JOIN actions on actions.rule_id=rules.id
WHERE (
 (conditions.field='temperature' and conditions.operator='>' and data_table.temperature > conditions.value)
 OR (conditions.field='temperature' and conditions.operator='<' and data_table.temperature < conditions.value)
 OR (conditions.field='water level' and conditions.operator='>' and data_table.water_level > conditions.value)
 OR (conditions.field='water level' and conditions.operator='<' and data_table.water_level < conditions.value))
  AND data_table.your_timestamp_column > '2020-07-22 10:01:02' -- the last time your job ran.
```

You can store the timestamp the job last ran in any persistent
storage. It's fine to have a table with just job_name and
last_completion_time columns that your job queries on startup to get
the value to use for the timestamp comparision and then UPDATEs with
the max of the processed data_table timestamps when it finishes.

Your WHERE clause to map the field & operator to a SQL expression will
be quite large, but this kind of thing is going to be verbose one way
or another. Maybe you can instead use a CASE statement to pull out the
field value so that the number of clauses you have scales with the
number of fields + number of operators instead of number of fields *
number of operators, something like:

```
SELECT
actions.* FROM (
  SELECT actions, t, conditions,
  CASE WHEN conditions.field='temperature' THEN t.temperature
       WHEN conditions.field='water level' THEN t.water_level
  END AS data_value
  data_table t
  JOIN rules on rules.device_id=t.device_id
  JOIN conditions on conditions.rule_id=rules.id
  JOIN actions on actions.rule_id=rules.id
  WHERE data_table.your_timestamp_column > '2020-07-22 10:01:02'
) AS inner_1
WHERE (
  (conditions.operator = '>' AND data_value > conditions.value)
  OR (conditions.operator = '<' AND data_value > conditions.value)
)
```

but this will run into problems if the possible fields for data_value
don't have the same type. You can kind of get around this by having a
column-per-type and then defining sets of available operators for each type:

```
-- ...
  CASE WHEN conditions.field='temperature' THEN t.temperature
       WHEN conditions.field='water level' THEN t.water_level
  END AS data_value_numeric,
  CASE WHEN conditions.field='device is enabled' THEN t.device_is_enabled
  END AS data_value_bool
-- ...
WHERE
(
  (conditions.operator = '>' AND data_value_numeric > conditions.numeric_value)
  OR (conditions.operator = '<' AND data_value_numeric > conditions.numeric_value)
  OR (conditions.operator = '=' AND data_value_bool > conditions.bool_value)
)
```

But we're pretty far into the weeds at this point. Hopefully this can
get you started.

Comment: Hi, my apologies for the delay in responding, I am still trying to work this out, using your suggestions. It's a logical question, not so much a technical problem. I think I may have a solution, and will post it once I get it to work. Thanks again